# connect facebook and twitter to wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, twitter

i have seen some blogs where they ask you to share the blog using facebook or twitter. Following that action, a email subscription box apprears for some free stuff. how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plugin such as this one must be installed to your WordPress blog:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/share-this/